Overlaying Heatmaps
i need to do a cross analysis with :
Two heatmaps
a: interne data (Blue)
b : externe data (red)
on a map
the idea is the extract the areas where only the blue appears
any suggestions the files are shape format
i have two suggestions :
pixel overlying analysis turning heatmap two image in that case i can lose infos because i musse fixe a scale
or still looking into this option find a methode where i can use overlay heatmap without turning it into image
this is the empirical analysis visualy i want to do it with python to analyse in lot 

I doubt that they are shapefiles, they look like rasters to me.

i created a heatmap to get a global idea
